# Slam toolbox map jumps on linear movements

Tags: slam, scan, ros-iron, map-to-odom

I'm running slam toolbox on iron using the default settings and am having an issue with, what I believe, is the scan matching.  My robot can rotate in place and generate a map of decent quality.  When I move the robot forward, the map->odom jumps as if the scan matching failed.  If I turn off scan matching, then I can generate a decent map until odom eventually does drift and the map gets corrupted.  I believe my robot's odometry is "good" and though I don't really know what is considered good, it returns to the odom starting point fairly well in real life.

What can cause such jumps to occur?  If you watch the gif below (I had to reduce the gif size and drop every other frame so in reality the robot moved at half this speed), you see me rotate the robot to fill in the entire map.  The laser is inside the robot and doesn't have a perfect 360-degree view, but I filter anything within 0.75m to be safe.  I then move the robot forward and that's when the map jumps.  Finally, I move it back to starting point and and it stays 'shifted' but when I move it back just a smudge more, it snaps back to the original map, which I assume means the scan match worked.  It's as if scan matching only works from the original starting point and fails when translated from it.

[image]

Comment: Hey have you figured this out yet? Im having a very similar issue (Cant comment, not enough reputation lol) link to my issue: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/109719/overlapping-while-mapping-with-slam-toolbox-even-with-good-odometry

Comment: I switched to cartographer which appears to rely heavily on the IMU and it doesn't jump and seems pretty stable.  Never solved the slamtoolbox issue.