# Overlapping while mapping with slam toolbox (Even with good odometry)

Tags: ros2, slam

**Required Info:**

- Operating System:

  - Ubuntu 22.04
- Installation type:

  - Binaries
- ROS Version

  - ROS 2 Humble
- Version or commit hash:

  - Not sure?
- Laser unit:

  - RP Lidar A2

##### Steps to reproduce the issue

- Launch Robot base driver (Including Odom and IMU)
- Launch EKF Filter from Robot_localisation package to fuse odom with IMU (Otherwise there's quite a bit of drift after a while)
- Launch Online Async Mapping

###### A link to my [rosbag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4S0KpnTX5uilfCr7-5Osme6EawNMSuT/view?usp=drive_link). please note that I was recording raw odometry so there is no filtered odom in this rosbag. Not sure how helpful it'd be.

##### Here's what my filtered Odometry looks like though:

Only a drift of about 50 CM after traveling 240 ish meters

[image]

##### Expected behavior

- A good map with no overlaps

##### Actual behavior

- With scan matching on the map is horrible.
  [image]
- Without scan matching and instead, just loop closure, it's much better. But still, there's an overlap while on the way back from the long straight path. The loop closure doesn't seem to make a difference. There no "jump" of the map to correct the small drifts to prevent the overlaps
  [image]

##### Additional information

Here's the ekf yaml:

```
  ros__parameters:

    # Plugin params
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    use_map_saver: true
    mode: mapping

    # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
    # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
    # will use pose
    # map_file_name: "/home/ros2_ws/src/tarkbot_robot/maps/roomV3_Serial"
    # map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    # map_start_at_dock: true

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 12.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.0
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
    enable_interactive_mode: true

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: false
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 10
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 6.0
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 20.0
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 0.5   

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.9  
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true
```

I have already tried playing around with params relating to loop closure and scan matching but saw no success so far. Since loop closure doesnt actually make a difference here im starting to think it could be due to the fact that the drift is very small so loop closure ignores that? Which param exactly tells loop closure to loop for even the smallest differences and try to correct it? if that makes sense.